# Do I need to install MySql separately on Windows 7 if I already have MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, wamp, mysql-workbench

I have installed MySql Workbench 6.3 CE on Windows 7 , I was assuming it installed MySql for me as well. Although now on command prompt it gives me

> Can't connect to MySQL server on Localhost error message

Do I need to install MySql separately in this instance then? I see MySQL.exe in workbench folder, I assumed thats the MySql itself.

Thanks.

Comment: To install MySQL database on local computer for development purpose you need to install XAMPP or MAMP or others available web development packages. MySQL workbench provides a visual console to easily administer MySQL.

Comment: I am using it to manage remote databases hence.

Comment: remote mysql database at host provider side is always blocked for external access, you can do two things, 1- access admin panel and manage your database from myphpadmin OR 2- use SSH secure channel access, not all web host provides SSH access, so you can ask your provider if they do offer this service. that way you can manage your database from your local machine lie mysql workbench

Comment: Btw I suggest u to download and use heidi sql it has build in SSH connection, very nice and easy tool, alternative to workbench.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ Yes I did try Heidisql but I dont see an easy option to clone an existing db on there.

Comment: heidi will only work if you have SSH or local mysql, I wrote al ready it wont work with remote, there is not easy way, you can log to your web provider admin panel, and use myphpadmin to dump the database OR SSH

Comment: There are 2 versions of MYSQL Workbench. One comes with an instance of MYSQL and one does not. I guess you go the wrong one. I thing this one is the [full version](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) Of course if you eventually want to have Apache and PHP as well then download and install WAMPServer or XAMPP or MAMP if you are a Mac user

Comment: @RiggsFolly There is not a version of MySQL Workbench that includes MySQL server. To others regarding SSH, Workbench can also connect via SSH.

Comment: @PhilipOlson I am sure there is, as I have in the past had to help people who have installed it, and then installed WAMPServer. and been confused by having 2 MySQL Servers on their system.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Perhaps you're referring to MySQL Installer for Windows, an application that manages (installs/configures/downloads) all MySQL products (including MySQL Workbench, MySQL Server, MySQL Notifier, and so on).

Comment: Thats probably it. MySQL Installer for 5.6 for Windows. Thats the link I put in the previous message. You might be surprised how many people use that rather than the simple MYSQL Workbench link. That page soes not make it very obvious to the first time browser

Comment: Wow with all the comments and even an answer with +1, I feel it is a relevant question and does not deserve the -1

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thats the one I used. I  do not see any option in it that brings MySql along

Comment: @pal4life I linked to MySQL Installer in the answer. Now, use it to install MySQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, MySQL Workbench does not bundle nor install MySQL server. Your error indicates a missing local MySQL server connection. If you want to connect and use a local MySQL instance then you must install a local MySQL server. Since this question is Windows specific, you should use the official [MySQL Installer for Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) to install and manage both.

In summary, Workbench includes a MySQL client (something you can connect to a remote or local MySQL server with) but it does not include MySQL server.

Comment: I installed via the url and it installed MySql Fabric 1.61. & MySql Utilities 1.6.1, still the mysql path does not resolve. Did it actually install MySql for me?

Comment: @pal4life Those are different, you need MySQL Server. Try MySQL Server 5.6.